# JavaScript - Complexity for the below Executions (forEach vs forEach-indexOf)

Tags: javascript, foreach, time-complexity

Problem Statement:- arr1 is an ordered array with values 3,4 and 5.In the list shown below all the objects whose property "c" matches with that of the elements of the array should be updated with index +1 of the found index at arr1.

I have two different ways of achieving the same, which one has a better time complexity and which one should be chosen?

```js
var arr1 = [3,4,5];
var list = [{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:1,b:2,c:3},{a:2,b:3,c:5},{a:3,b:4,c:4}];
output: [{a:1,b:2,c:1},{a:1,b:2,c:1},{a:2,b:3,c:3},{a:3,b:4,c:3}];
```

1: Find the index and then update the index:

```js
list.forEach((obj) => {
  var i = arr1.indexOf(obj.c);
  if(i > -1) {
     obj.c = i +1;
  }
});
```

2. Using two forEach loops.

```js
arr1.forEach((id,index) => {
  list.forEach((obj) => {
     if(obj.c === id){
       obj.c = index+1;
     }
  })
});
```

Which is the better way to write and why?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the question - #2. m.forEach is list.forEach

Comment: They're both the same. The call to `.indexOf()` will iterate through `arr1`, so in both cases the time complexity is the product `arr1.length * list.length`.

Comment: Problem with second one is it will visit every index after it found a match unlike indexOf would

Comment: The complexity is `O(m*n)` either way. Well, `O(m*n)` and `O(n*m)` but the order of multiplication doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) with value and index in advance, with a single loop.

And another loop for all elements of `list`, where `c` gets an update if necessary.

---

An instance of `Map` is a data structure to keep a key value relation with a fast access **O(1)** to the value.

```js
var array = [3, 4, 5],
    list = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 2, b: 3, c: 5 }, { a: 3, b: 4, c: 4 }],
    values = new Map;

array.forEach(Map.prototype.set, values);

list.forEach(o => {
    if (values.has(o.c)) o.c = values.get(o.c) + 1;
});

console.log(list);
```